# How to kill all entities in a custom dimension?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to kill all entities in a custom dimension named "console" except myself, armor stands, and items. At the moment, it is killing all entities in all dimensions except me, armor stands, and items.

This is the command

```
execute in minecraft:console run kill @e [type=!minecraft:armor_stand,name=!MaximumCalamity,type=!minecraft:item]
```

Comment: saying `in <dimension>` means that the entity must be IN that dimension

Comment: @Penguin That's exactly what the asker wants, only the entities in that dimension. They say that the unwanted behaviour is that it's affecting entities in all dimensions.

Comment: Are you sure the `console` dimension is definitely in the `minecraft` namespace? That seems unusual

Answer (score 1):

Your selector selects entities outside of your dimension. You can use the `distance` trick to only select entities inside the specified dimension:

```
execute in minecraft:console run kill @e[distance=0..,type=!armor_stand,name=!MaximumCalamity,type=!item]
```

Or, you can use a [predicate](https://misode.github.io/predicate/):

```
{
  "condition": "minecraft:entity_properties",
  "entity": "this",
  "predicate": {
    "location": {
      "dimension": "minecraft:console"
    }
  }
}
```

Paste this into a `.json` file, and place it into the correct folder path inside your datapack.

You can then select entities more efficiently with:

```
kill @e[predicate=namespace:predicate_file_name,type=!armor_stand,name=!MaximumCalamity,type=!item]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do that, but I think you have to be in that specific dimension to do that with this command:

```
/execute in console run kill@e[type=!minecraft:Player, type=!minecraft:item, type=!minecraft:armor_stand]
```

I haven't tested it yet because I can't get into the `console` dimension because it isn't in vanilla Minecraft, but I'm pretty sure it should work.

Comment: there appear to be a few error in this answer, (what is the pacific realm?) and you seem to have misunderstood the premise of the question